# One field out of several returns "null" in jQuery $.get()

Tags: php, jquery, get

For some reason, 'price' returns null whereas all of the others aren't an issue. Any ideas why this might be?

MySQL:

Table called 'nights' with columns called 'name', 'price', 'day', 'queue jump', 'closing' and 'doors'. They are all populated.

eventinfo.php:

```
<?php

header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');

include('functions.php');
connect();

$night = $_POST['club'];
$night = mysql_real_escape_string($night);

$query = "SELECT * FROM nights WHERE name = '" .$night. "'";

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $items = array();

    if($result && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        $items[] = array("price"=>$row['price'], "day"=>getLongDateString($row['day']), "queuejump"=>$row['queue jump'], "closing"=>$row['closing']);
        }
    } 

    mysql_close(); 
    // convert into JSON format and print

    echo json_encode($items);
?>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#right_inside').html('<h2>' + $('#club').val() + '</h2>');
    });

    $('#club').change(function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "eventinfo.php",
            data:  $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                $('#right_inside').html('<h2>' + $('#club').val() + '<span style="font-size: 14px"> (' + data[0].day + ')</h2><p>Entry: ' + data[0].price + '</p><p>Queue jump: ' + data[0].queuejump + '</p><p>Guestlist closes at ' + data[0].closing + '</p>');
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                },
            dataType: "json"
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Does your price start with a $ sign?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this - MySQL didn't like the £ sign. `&pound;` or `&#163;` works better.